# Though ADB wifi Debugging want to install one app to 100 devices simultaneously

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

I want to connect many devices with ADB server.My Idea is to install one apk to approx 100 devices simultaneously . please tell me best approach which I can use.

Comment: You can get so many devices with adb wifi and yeah you can run it in particular device one by one

Comment: You need to install one by one ...

Comment: Not in particular device. I will install the app in 100 separate devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the exact use case is. But for such a large number of devices its preferred to upload the application on google playstore as Alpha/Beta release. The app wont be visible publicly, but all registered alpha/beta accounts(devices) will receive updates/installation of application.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en